# Best way to pass data from a root to deeper child widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. My flutter widget tree is getting deeper and deeper, I want to know which is the best method to pass data from a root to a widget which is much deeper from it. I'm currently passing it as a constructor from widget to widget.
My current implementation is given below

```
Level1(data: data)
  Level2(data: data)
    Level3(data: data)
       Level4(data: data)
```

suppose my data is retrieved from DB in level1 widget and it is used in level4 widget. As we see, my current implementation is considerably messy. How this is generally done? what is the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to use `Provider`. You can find more about it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Basically, you create provider of the data at the top-most level like:

```
class Level1 {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider<Data>(
      create: (_) => Something(),
      child: Level2 (
         // stuff of level 2
      ),
    ),
  }
}
```

`Something` in this case bight be a change notifier.

You can then access it at a lower level with:

```
final provider = Provider.of<Something>(context);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think Provider can handle my concern much clean and clearer.

Comment: @VishnuPrasad: Glad I can help you. Don't forget to accept the answer so that your question will be displayed as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Inherited widget - If you want to avoid using any third party library..

More can be found here - https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1

and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk

```
class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final int accountId;
  final int scopeId;

  MyInheritedWidget(accountId, scopeId, child): super(child);
  
  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyInheritedWidget old) =>
    accountId != old.accountId || scopeId != old.scopeId;
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int accountId;
  final int scopeId;
  
  MyPage(this.accountId, this.scopeId);
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MyInheritedWidget(
      accountId,
      scopeId,
      const MyWidget(),
     );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  const MyWidget();
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // somewhere down the line
    const MyOtherWidget();
    ...
  }
}

class MyOtherWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  const MyOtherWidget();
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myInheritedWidget = MyInheritedWidget.of(context);
    print(myInheritedWidget.scopeId);
    print(myInheritedWidget.accountId);
    ...
```

Comment: How will this not be "considerably messy"? You are coupling your Widgets extremely tight together making changes and re-usability really hard.

Comment: Thank you towhid and Alex, for your response. Can you please also suggest any third party plugin which effectively deals with this.So I can come in a conclusion. Thanks again!

Comment: It is basically depends on the personal preference and project requirement. If the project is complicated than Provider is recommended, but for simple project it can do the job @alex